# ColumnWidths property in VBA does not seem to work as documented

Tags: vba

Note - the document I reference in the title is here:[ColumnWidths Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/columnwidths-property)

I have a columnwidths property that I set in code based upon the items in a query for a listbox.  This works fine:

```
colString = "0 in; 2 in; 2 in; 1 in; 0 in;"
Me.lstListbox.ColumnWidths = colString
```

I have a query which has quite a few columns, 44 to be exact.  Two things about what happens  when this ColumnWidths property is set for this query:

- When I set the ColumnWidths for those 44 columns, so that my colString is `"0 in; 2 in; 2 in; 1 in; 0 in;"` plus about 39 other column sizes (by inch), I get an error 2176, "The setting for this property is too long."  I get it that the string being applied to the property (about 267 chars) is too long, I'm guessing the limit is 255, just no place in the documentation that confirms this.
- So, my string is too long to apply to the ColumnWidths property.  Looking at the referenced documentation, the default is measured in points, with 72 points being an inch.  Or I can specify `"0; 144; 144; 72; 0;...etc"`, which should cut down on the length of the string I use for this property  That should be a good substitute.  Substituting the following, however, does not work:

```
    colString = "0; 144; 144; 72; 0;"
    Me.lstListbox.ColumnWidths = colString
```

The behavior of the property seems to be incorrect in the VBA documentation.  That's one thing.

The other thing - any suggestions on how I can cut the length of the string applied to the property and achieve the same goal - which is set widths in the listbox for the data?

Comment: The documentation does not include spaces after the semi-colons (and does not have a semi-colon at the end).  Your code *does*.  Are these a transcription error when writing the code on StackOverflow, or how your code actually appears?  Similarly, you have an extra double-quote in your posted code — is that also in your used code?

Comment: A small help: The default setting for a column is 1 inch or 72 points. So you can remove those entries from your list - e.g `"0;144;144;72;0"` would become `"0;144;144;;0"`

Comment: Thanks for the input Chronocidal.   The extra spaces and the semicolon at the end of the string do not matter; either way the string does not work in the property.  I did update the posted code to remove the extra double-quote - that was an error in posting the question.

Comment: CLR, I did test this out.  Removing the default - 72 (points) - and leaving it blank does not default to 1 inch.  It seems to default to 1/4 inch, which isn't a bad option, but definitely not what the VBA documentation says for the property.   Aside from trying to figure out a solution, my post here is an observation that the documentation does not match the functionality for this property, and the Microsoft/Office VBA  support and feedback folks who manage that and who have funneled feedback to this Stack Overflow site should either correct the documentation, or correct the functionality.

Comment: As a solution, I shaved off the space prior to the semicolon --> colString = "0 in;2 in;2 in;1 in;0 in; ... etc."  For a 44 column query, it works out to be 224 chars, which gets me under the assumed 255 char limit for the ColumnWidths property.  That would leave me with potentially 6 more columns before I bump up against the limit again.